# I'm facing an error with jcalender code in netbeans

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror, java.util.calendar

I'm making an airplane reservation system with java and when I run the code, it results into an error.

The error I'm receiving is:

```
"Incompatible types: Date cannot be converted into calendar."
```

And it appears at `dateChooserCombo1.setSelectedDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());` and at `dt=dateChooserCombo1.getSelectedDate();`
What can I do to eliminate this errors

```
 try
    {
        Class .forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a_r_s","root","");
        dateChooserCombo1.setSelectedDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    final Object[] columnNames=new String[] {"Date","Flight Name","Departure Time","BC Seats Available","XC Seats Available","EC Seats Available"};
    DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel(columnNames,0);        
    origin=jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString();
    target=jComboBox4.getSelectedItem().toString();
    fclass=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();

    dt=dateChooserCombo1.getSelectedDate();      
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    strdtver2=(String) sdf1.format(dateChooserCombo1.getSelectedDate());
    /**************************************
    //Seven days flight calendar processing
    **************************************/
    dt7=dateChooserCombo1.getSelectedDate();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(dt7);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
    dt7 = cal.getTime();
    strdtver3=(String) sdf1.format(dt7);
```

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead I believe that you just need `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), instead.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error because your code is not complete, at least there are some declarations and some imports missing. Could you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Answer (score 1):

Date and Calendar are not compatible types. You must convert between them:

```
Date date= new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(date);
```

Also make sure you use the correct Java Date type: `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: Sorry, tl;dr :D Anyway, what about the second part of my answer? What type is declared your Date variable? `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Which is the type declared for those variables? Like someone commented you should provide a complete example to allow us help you.